# Chemfig newcommand for Lewis structures

Tags: chemfig

So I'm trying to create my own style package for drawing simple lewis structures. I want to do a \newcommand type of thing that has the option for me to not only put in the atoms, but also an option for bonds as well (<, =, -, or >). How can I accomplish this? I tried just replacing the bond designation symbol by {#4} but it did not work of course. Please let me know.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{chemfig,chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=all}

\newcommand{\Linear}[4]{\chemfig{{#1}
            ( {#4}[:180] {#2})
            ( -[:0] {#3})}}

\begin{document}

\chemfig{C
    ( =[:180] O)
    ( <[:0] O)}

\Linear{C}{O}{O}{=}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to remove some braces. In more detail, you put all the arguments `#1`, `#2`, `#3` and `#4` into braces, but you should not do that.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig,chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules=all}

\newcommand{\Linear}[4]{\chemfig{#1
            ( #4[:180] #2)
            ( -[:0] #3)}}

\begin{document}

\chemfig{C
    ( =[:180] O)
    ( <[:0] O)}

\Linear{C}{O}{O}{=}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's perfect! thank you!